# Why if I use "C" it's wrong but if I use "c" it's working?

Tags: c

Write a single statement to accomplish each of the following. Assume that variables c (which stores a character), x, y and z are of type int, variables d, e and f are of type double, variable ptr is of type char * and arrays s1[100] and s2[100] are of type char.

Determine whether the value of c is a letter. Use the conditional operator to print " is a " or " is not a " when the result is displayed.

```
printf("%s",((c >= 141 && c<= 172) || (c>= 101 && c<= 132)) ? "is a " : "is not a ");
```

Comment: Code in 'C' is case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

The C programming has a feature of being case-sensitive. `C` and `c` have different ASCII values as characters AND they're different too as identifiers.